# ¿Cómo puedo recibir los datos que me retorna un controlador a servicio angular?

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, .net

Necesito que desde mi servicio angular se reciban los datos del json que trae el controlador de c#, mi problema es que no sé como recibir esos datos que ya está retornando el controlador

**Estos son los datos que el controlador retorna:**

```
{
    "Exito": "true",
    "Error": "",
    "Noticia": "EXISTE",
    "Fecha": "",
    "nombre": "dany3",
    "direccion": "dany3",
    "EsServicio": "true"
}
```

**Este es el código del método en el servicio de Angular:**

```
ConsultarUsuario(cedula): Observable<any>{
  let url = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('webConfig'))["urlServicioPrueba"]+"/FUNUsuario/ConsultarUsuario";
  return this.servicioFw.post(
    url
    ,
    {
      cedula:cedula,
    },  
    httpOptions
    //{headers: new HttpHeaders({ "Content-Type": "application/json","Content-Types":"12345"})}
  );
}
```

**Este es el código del ts de Angular el cual llama al servicio:**

```
  ConsultarUsuario() {
  this.servicioUsuario.ConsultarUsuario(this.cedula).subscribe(res => {
      if (res.respuesta == "true") {
        alert(res.Noticia);
      } else {
        alert(res.Error);
      }

    },
      (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        alert("Error" + err.error);
      });
  }
```

Comment: No logro entender de todo tu pregunta, veo que el servicio funciona correctamente y te retorna un objeto, cual es el problema?

Comment: @IvanIsayenko  mi inconveniente está en como puedo recibir los datos en el ts de angular, yo estoy usando el return en el servicio para que me traiga lo que viene del controlador, pero no sé como invocar esos valores para consulta en el ts, espero me entienda

Comment: quieres sacar la respuesta del servicio fuera del ts que lo llama?

Comment: Te doy un ejemplo, el html, llama al ts, el ts llama al servicio de angular, el servicio de angular llama al controlador, este llama al modelo, hasta aquí es un proceso que ya está funcionando, ahora, el modelo le responde al controlador y el controlador retorna los datos a angular, específicamente al servicio, bueno, aquí va mi problema, el servicio de angular le retorna los datos al ts, cómo puedo hacer yo para mostrar los datos recibidos por ese servicio en un alert? O uno de los datos recibidos, esto quiero hacerlo ya que estoy haciendo un input de consulta y quiero que cuando oprima el bo

Comment: puedes añadir el apartado html donde quieres que se vean los datos de la consulta?